# Determining who won in a JavaScript tic-tac-toe game

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

```
 var winning = [
           [0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5],
           [6, 7, 8],
           [0, 3, 6],
           [1, 4, 7],
           [2, 5, 8],
           [0, 4, 8],
           [2, 4, 6]
        ];
//this are all the possible ways to win    

function checkwin (box) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winning.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(box + winning[i][0]).innerHTML && document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML && document.getElementById(box + winning[i][2]).innerHTML);{
            alert(innerHTML + 'won') 
        }
    }
}
```

I was attempting to loop through each box to check for a winner
I used a for loop to create the boxes and had to use `box.id = 'box' + i` to give each box an id which are the numbers.

Comment: When you run that code, what does it do? What exactly do you want it to do instead?

Comment: it shows an error. I wanted to loop through the arrays and check if x or o won the game. I'm just not sure how to do it

Comment: What is the error that it shows? The content error messages are very useful when programming.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier .. and the error is referring to the array

Answer (score 0):

Your if check is wrong, you are just checking to see if they are truthy. You are not checking to see if they are equal.

Another bug: you have a random semicolon in the code. 
Another bug: you never defined innerHTML.

```
if (document.getElementById(box + winning[i][0]).innerHTML && 
    document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML && 
    document.getElementById(box + winning[i][2]).innerHTML);{
                                                           ^---BUG
```

I assume you want to check that they are equal

```
var cell1 = document.getElementById(box + winning[i][0]).innerHTML;
var cell2 = document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML;
var cell3 = document.getElementById(box + winning[i][2]).innerHTML;
if (cell1===cell2 && cell1===cell3) {
    alert(cell1);
    break;
}
```

Comment: What if all the boxes are empty tho?  Then the winner will be ""

Comment: So have a check that it is not equal to whatever the default is.

Comment: x and o are in the boxes when the player clicks

Comment: my array seems to be incorrect. is there any way i can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if (document.getElementById(box + winning[i][0]).innerHTML && 
    document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML && 
    document.getElementById(box + winning[i][2]).innerHTML);{
```

to:

```
if (document.getElementById(box + winning[i][0]).innerHTML == document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML &&
    document.getElementById(box + winning[i][1]).innerHTML == document.getElementById(box + winning[i][2]).innerHTML){
```